# Apex test class for ctr extn

Tags: apex

Null values not covered:

```
public with sharing class AccountCustomerExtn {
    public Customer__c customerObj {get; set;}
    public Product__c productObj {get; set;}
    public AccountCustomerExtn(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    customerObj = (Customer__c)controller.getRecord();
    productObj = new Product__c();
    }
    public void retrieveProductData()
    {
        if(!String.isBlank(customerObj.Product__c))
        {
            productObj = [select Id, Description__c from Product__c where Id=:customerObj.Product__c];
            customerObj.Product_Description__c = productObj.Description__c;
        }
        else
        {
            customerObj.Product_Description__c = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class AccountCustomerExtn_Test 
{
    static testMethod void insertCustomer()
    {

        Product__c prod = new Product__c(Name='Test', Description__c='Test');
        insert prod;
        Customer__c cust = new Customer__c(Name = 'Test', Email__c='sohel@test.com', Mobile_Number__c='9701316764',  Product__c=prod.Id,  Product_Description__c = prod.Description__c);
        insert cust;
        ctr.retrieveProductData();
}
```

Below code not covered:

```
        customerObj.Product_Description__c = NULL;
```

Comment: If the below answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 0):

Create another testmethod in which Customer has no Product to cover the lines.

```
static testMethod void insertCustomerWithoutProduct(){

   Customer__c cust = new Customer__c(Name = 'Test', Email__c='sohel@test.com', Mobile_Number__c='9701316764',Product_Description__c='Test', Account_Number__c='1234567890');
   insert cust;
   ctr.retrieveProductData();
}
```

Update the customSave() method by adding a debug statement in the catch block to capture the exception.

Comment: I guess the uncovered line is covered now, so please mark it resolved and useful